# How to see the tags which are ignored by the browser?

Tags: html, meta-tags

I was viewing a page in firefox/chrome.
I found that major chunks of information are not being rendered.

What I found is - The browsers are completely ignoring some of the html tags which are recently introduced.Example: `<title>`within the body ,`<aside>`,`<section>`...

I want to know is there a way to find out which tags are ignored by the browser, and if possible, why?

Comment: my mistake...I meant section

Comment: Where/When is `title` allowed in `body`?

Answer (score 0):

Check http://html5test.com/

It shows what elements are supported in your browser (or specific versions of different browsers).

Comment: Thanks for the link.I am aware of the html5test.But what I am looking for is the final set of tags that the browser has rendered(after ignoring the unsupported tags).It will be helpful for me for debugging.